# How to provide different beans depending on runtime parameter using @Bean method

Tags: java, spring

I am trying create a @Configuration factory bean that should create other (prototype) beans depending on a runtime parameter. I want to use spring java-based configuration but somehow I could not make it work.

Here is an example:

```
enum PetType{CAT,DOG;}

abstract class Pet {    
}

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
class Cat extends Pet{
}

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
class dog extends Pet{
}

@Configuration
public class PetFactory{    
    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public Pet pet(PetType type){
        if(type == CAT){
            return new Cat();
        }else
            return new Dog();
    }
}

petFactory.animal(PetType.CAT);
```

I checked spring docs and all related questions asked here but I end up in the case of supplying runtime parameters to the created bean. And I need to supply runtime parameters to the factory that must use them to create different beans.

**EDIT:**
Seems (currently) there is no way to define a parameter to a @Bean annotated method as
"runtime". Spring assumes method parameters will be used as constructor args for the new bean and so it tries to satisfy this dependency with container-managed beans.

Comment: Look into profiles. Where is the `PetType` coming from?

Comment: PetType comes from user input.

Comment: If it's coming from user input, why do you need to leverage Spring to create them (you're invoking new, so Spring isn't managing them anyhow)? Have the factory be a spring component, but have something else drive the creation of PetType -- that can be in your interceptors, controllers or wherever.

Comment: That is not correct, Spring IS managing them, I am only instantiating the bean. So I get autowiring, transaction, scoped proxies that I actually need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using @Configurable:

```
class Factory {

    Pet newPetOfType(PetType type) {
        switch (type) {
            case CAT: return new Cat();
            ...
        }
    }

    @Configurable
    private static class Cat extends Pet {
        @Autowired private Prop prop;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems interesting but would require AspectJ weaving that I need to explicitly enable. Currently I use only Spring AOP for transaction proxies.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like it could be a good use of the Spring Profiles feature. Here you can read about [Java configurations](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/), and here about [XML Profiles](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/).

Your profile would define a Pet bean. Your factory could then wire that bean in.

To modify which profile you use, simply add: -Dspring.profiles.active=dog or -Dspring.profiles.active=cat (or whatever you name them).

Comment: This is possible but is a way "static". I need to create cats and dogs dynamically when required.

Answer (score 1):

You can just **@Autowire** your PetFactory bean into required bean and call **animal()** method with required type in runtime, like in the following approach:

```
@Configuration    
public class AppConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public Pet getPet(PetType type) {

        if(type == CAT){
            return new Cat();
        } else
            return new Dog();
    }

}

//...
// Then in required class
@Service
public class PetService {

    @Autowired
    private AppConfiguration configuration;

    //.....

    public Pet getPetByType(PetType type) {
        return configuration.getPet(type);
    }

}
```